# Typescript File Paths

Tags: html, typescript

I am using Typescript with Visual Studio 2015.

I have a folder of sprite images called "Sprites" in my root folder. When developing the app I reference it using "../Sprites/someSprite.png" and this is fine when I am debugging in VS

However, if I try to open the index.htm file directly, the images are not shown.

Why not?

Comment: Are there any errors in the console or [network tab](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools#improving-network-performance)?

Comment: Can you show the code?

Answer (score 0):

> However, if I try to open the index.htm file directly, the images are not shown.
>   Why not?

Two potential reasons:

- Some browsers will not allow you to read files on the file system. This is a safety feature and you can turn it off > search for your browser.
- The file paths at runtime (served from IIS or something) might not map to file paths relative to the html file > check your view system (ASP.net MVC or webforms or something else).